# How to write to shell without scrolling?

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal, output

Creating shell output for a game, but don't want the window to scroll with each update of the game board. How to do it?

Working in Ruby.

Comment: Firstly, understand the difference between a terminal and a shell.  You're question has nothing to do with a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works well using the following. Does not use a gem.

```
require "curses"
include Curses

class Display
  def self.show board
    win = Window.new(20, 200, 0, 0) # 20 lines x 200 chars
    win.addstr board
    win.refresh
    win.close
  end

  def self.initialize
    crmode
    curs_set 0 # Hide cursor
    init_screen
  end
end
```

How to use:

```
Display.initialize

while true do
  Display.show board
  board.update # Or whatever the game needs to do...
end
```

Reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html

Answer (score 4):

[`curses`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/index.html) will you give fine control over the text output of your application.

Comment: That link provides no useful information. How to use it? Do I need a gem?

Comment: The URL contains "stdlib".